# Page Navigation Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Page Navigation in Windows Phone 8.1 is:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

or with parameter:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), param);
```

and on the target page:

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  myTextBox.Text = e.Parameter.ToString();
}
```

or

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  var val = (myClass)e.Parameter;
  myTextBox.Text = val.Text;
}
```

But in my case I want to do something with those data received on the target page. For example I want to let the user edit those data and save them as new data.
I've searched for hours and all I could find was just page navigation with or without parameter and not the one I've described above. Is there any way to approach this? Any suggestion, solution is appreciated!

Comment: When you say "edit", what do you want to do with the edited version? Pass it back to the caller? Save to a web service?

Comment: As I've said above save the new data locally in the ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings

Comment: @ShaheemJohn Where is your problem? Just save it to the local settings. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx

Comment: Yes all I want to do with the received data on the target page is to save them locally in the ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings that is it.

Comment: @cansik The link you've sent it do not explain my scenario.

Comment: I still do not know where you have problems? Getting the data or saving the data or manipulating the data?

Comment: @cansik Let me explain first a little more: In my application on one of the pages I have a list with selectable items. If the user select an item the page navigation takes place and goes to the second page and on the second page I have a text box which is editable and the user is allowed to make changes to the content of this particular text box. From the first page to the second page, navigation with parameter goes fine, the problem is on the second page when the user changes the content of the text box. I want to save the NEW data locally for next use. How can I SAVE the new data locally.

Comment: So your issue has nothing to do with navigation, but saving data locally instead?

Comment: @RowlandShow You are partly right but in this particular scenario I have to use page navigation first and then save data. So page navigation goes first and I end up with the data received after navigation which should be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass your text and the settings name to your edit form, use a KeyValuePair:

```
//figure out how to get the text out of the list
var myItem = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mytextsetting", "listbox.selecteditem.text");
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), myItem);
```

On the second page, you can now store the incoming parameter:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string> _myItem;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   _myItem = e.Parameter as KeyValuePair<string, string>;
   myTextBox.Text = myItem.Value;
}
```

Now when the user wants to save the edited text:

```
_myItem.Value = myTextBox.Text;

//save it to the settings
localSettings.Values[_myItem.Key] = _myItem.Value;
```